# Javascript function not always loading after element is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a Javasript function that doesn't *always* get run through. The function is under a jQuery.bind, that is attached to the video player on the page. Once the video player is ready the function should run, some elements of the functions depend on the duration of the video which can only be obtained once the video player is ready.

It seems to work a good majority of the time, but sometimes (3/10 times) it doesn't. Not sure why this is happening.

```
ML = (typeof ML === "undefined") ? {} : ML;
ML.player = null;

//Initialization of the video player
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var vidId = vidIdRaw.split("/");
    ML.player = new SV.Player({
        videoId: vidId[0]
    });
    //More functions are initialized under the document.ready

    //Waits for video player to be ready before executing function
    //This is the function that doesn't always run
    ML.player.bind('ready', function(obj) {
        var isReady = true;
        jQuery('#duration-time').html(formatTime(ML.player.getDuration()));
        //Functions initialized above are called and run here as well.
    }
}
```

I left most of the functions out as there is a lot of code I'd have to include. I've included the relevant information.

Comment: I'm not sure how the firing of events is going to pan out in jQuery, but based on the code I can see, my guess would be that 3/10 the player is ready before the document is ready. Is there a way to test if your player is ready in the document.ready function, and if it already is, run the code inside the bind?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about that. How can that happen though, I have the initialization of the video player under (document).ready. Shouldn't the video player always wait for the document to be ready first then?

Comment: So you are creating the SV.Player first and then listening for it to be ready. Is it possible that it's dispatching it's ready event so quickly that it happens before it returns to your document.ready function, where you then bind the event? Say if the video is cached? Is there a way to instantiate the player without injecting the video, and add the ready event BEFORE telling the player to load a video. That way it would always fire.
Again - I can only guess on what code you have posted, but if the event is not firing, that can only mean there is a bug in SV or the event order is the problem.

Comment: Toby and dipanda are probably right. Also, there is no native 'ready' event, it's a jQuery one and I assume it uses onreadystatechange to determine timing. It might not be flawless, try using the more native ones listed here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#mediaevents

Comment: @Toby I'm looking into this. I'm going to see if it's possible and how I can do it. Also wanted to mention I've tried testing with cache disabled through Chrome's dev tools, and the bug persists.

Comment: @casraf I'm trying this. Going to replace it with .onloadeddata. I will test it and update.

Comment: @Als26 - well the way you are using the player looks just how they recommend in their docs. So, assuming their code is not buggy, then the only other possibility I can think of is that something else in your code is causing the problem. Something with the iframe? What is ML?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the ready event on the player as soon as possible after its initialization; it's possible that the code mentioned as "More functions are initialized..." takes to long to execute and you miss the ready event on the player.

Comment: I forgot to mention the functions being initialized are being run under video player ready. It's as far up as possible. Sorry, edited the question to include this.